# numpy zero-dimension array to 1d

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in numpy: `[0 1 2 3]`

When I try to get the first element with a[0], it throws: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

If I use `for x in a: print(x)` Python throws `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

Attempting to make a list with `list(a)` throws `TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable`

How do I convert this list of numbers into a standard list?

Comment: Can you show how you created `a`?

Comment: It might help to see the `dtype`.  And just to be sure `type` and `shape`.  The errors are not consistent with the initial display.  Also try `repr(arr)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know how you created `a` so that we could try to reproduce the errors.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
print(a[0]) # 0

for x in a:
    print(x) # 0 1 2 3

# you can call list() to convert to a python list
print(list(a))

# you can also call the built-in numpy array method
print(a.tolist())

a = np.array(a)
print(a, type(a)) # [0 1 2 3] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(a[0]) # 0
print(a[1]) # 1
```

All of these operations succeed. Python 3.7.1, Numpy 1.15.4

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the type of the array, using `a=array('[0 1 2 3]', dtype='<U9')` I was able to replicate the firts two errors. If that is the case try the following

```
b=list(str(a))
newArray=[]
for val in b:
    try:
        newArray.append(int(val))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Python will not change automatically the value of a string to `int` or `float`as some others languajes. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, the third error isn't consistent with the others.  `list(a)` is essentially `[x for x in a]`, so should produce the same error, not one referencing a 'uint8' object.